# Xcode error after implementing AppLovin SDK

Tags: ios, applovin

I'm getting this error after I implementing AppLovin SDK.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/paulfrye/Documents/App Stuff/Apps/Flappy Fly/Flappy Fly/2702_flappypenguinpackage3/FlappyPenguin-2/Flappy\ Bird/SDK\'
ld: library not found for -lChartboost
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check library search path and remove back splash.

Or Drag chartboost library's parent folder to library search path window in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this in the future, I found a fix from [Here](http://www.reskinningapps.com/how-to/integrating-applovin-into-your-ios-game-with-xcode/#comment-2454) that (surprisingly) fixes the supposedly missing Chartboost library, even for projects not using AppLovin.

In XCode:

> 1. Click Build Phases
> 2. Click Link Binary with Libraries disclosure triangle.
> 3. Find libChartboost.a in the list.
> 4. Drag it up 2 or 3 position and release mouse.
> 5. Try and build again.
>      Often that will fix it.

Comment: I actually don't think this problem has anything to do with either Chartboost or AppLovin. Just Xcode and its questionable build chain :)